# Should I use router.isReady when fetching with react-query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, next.js, react-query

Been stuck on this issue for some time now trying to retro fit react-query in to my codebase.

I have a working version using getStaticProps.

I have been experimenting with router.isReady from next/router to try and force the page to wait for the router.query value to be present before passing it as props to the react hook.

Here is my code...

*pages/artist/[artistId].js*

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

import Head from "next/head";
import ArtistHeader from "../../components/ArtistHeader";
import UploadButton from "../../components/UploadButton";
import fetchArtist from "../../hooks/getArtists";

import styles from "../../styles/artistPage.module.css";

export default function Artist() {
  const { status } = useSession();
  const [artist, setArtist] = useState(null);
  const router = useRouter();
  const artistId = router.query.artistId;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "unauthenticated") {
      router.push("/auth/signin");
    }
  }, [status, router]);

  //check if router isReady
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!router.isReady) {
      return;
    }
  }, [router.isReady]);

  const { data, status: artistStatus } = useQuery(
    ["artist"],
    () => fetchArtist(artistId),
    {
      staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
      cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    }
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (artistStatus === "success") {
      setArtist(data);
    }
  }, [artistStatus, data]);

  return (
    <section className={styles.wrapper}>
      {/* <Head>
        <title>{artist.screenName}</title>
      </Head>
      <div className={styles.artistPage}>
        <ArtistHeader artist={artist} />
        <div className={styles.songContainer}>
          <UploadButton />
        </div>
      </div> */}
    </section>
  );
}
```

Here is the firestore data fetch...

*hooks/getArtists.js*

```
import { getDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../pages/api/auth/firebase/config";

export default async function fetchArtist(artistId) {
  console.log(artistId);
  const artistRef = doc(db, "users", artistId);
  const artistDoc = await getDoc(artistRef);
  if (artistDoc.exists()) {
    return artistDoc.data();
  } else {
    // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
    console.log("No such document!");
  }
}
```

I really want my data fetching to be separate and handled by react-query. Any ideas wwould be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't really need an `useEffect` just to check if `router.isReady`, and you also don't need the `artist` state since it's redundant, react-query takes care of this for you.

What you can do is disable the query using the `enabled` option of `useQuery` if `artistId` is `undefined`, that way you are preventing the request to be made on first render when the `query` object is empty.

```
  const { data: artist, status: artistStatus } = useQuery(
    ["artist"],
    () => fetchArtist(artistId),
    {
      staleTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
      cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
      enabled: Boolean(artistId) // or directly check router.isReady flag
    }
  );
```

**Note:** make sure to use [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) when trying to access `artist` object's properties since it will be `undefined` on first render.

**Reference to useQuery's enabled option:** https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/disabling-queries